# merging data in multiple columns into single column data in Dev Express

Tags: c#, devexpress

i have three columns, where i need to combine all these three column values into single column.

```
Metric  count  value1      value2
parlegi   2        -1         3
mangol    13       4          0
pizza     2       +12         -5
jax       0        -2          2
```

Now i need to merge cells in each row,i mean to display table with two columns as shown below. so end user report should display like below

```
Metric        count/value1/value2 
parlegi                 2/ -1/  3
mangol              13/ 4/0
pizza                 2/+12/-5
jax                     0/ -2/ 2
```

and here for positive values color should be green and negative values it should be red and zero with blue color.

Comment: are you using ASPxGridView or winforms xtragrid ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify where those columns get displayed, in ASPxGridView or XtraGrid. But in both cases you should investigate the Unbound Columns approach:

1. [ASPxGridView - How to: Add an Unbound Column to Supply Additional Data](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3770)
2. [XtraGrid - Unbound Columns](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1477)

Unbound columns are sort of virtual columns which don't have their counterpart columns in DB tables. So, using the unbound columns approach you can unite several DB column values into 1 single unbound column displayed in UI.

Comment: @  I need it for reporting so i think i need to use XRtablecells, but not sure. Here i need to concate three columns data into one column. If you show some code regarding this. If will be helpful

Comment: @daisy I can't show you any code because you didn't include any existing code for your grid/report. Add relevant code snippets with markup for your grid and codebehind. Then someone may try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<dx:GridViewDataColumn Caption="Count/Value1/Value2">
   <DataItemTemplate>
      <dx:ASPxLabel id="txtValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Count") + "/" + Eval("Value1") +"/"+ Eval("Value2")%'/>
   </DataItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataColumn>
```

You have to create a column like above to achieve your requirement.